# A good book to read with Chapter III of Neukirch's "ANT"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

The book [Algebraic Number Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540653996) from Neukirch is a beautiful book in ANT, but it still have a serious lack in examples and motivation to the concepts. I've already read the first two chapters of the book, complementing my reading with Ribenboim's [Classical Theory of Algebraic Numbers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387950702) and the online lecture notes from Milne on [Algebraic Number Theory](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ant.html).

But now the Chapter III seems a little bit *different* (no puns intended) from standard algebraic number theory and algebraic geometry courses, and if I have understood well the goal of this chapter, it wants to present a proof of Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch's theorem in such a fashion that you don't even have to know much algebraic geometry to understand.

So my question is: there is some book or some online material like lecture notes that fills the gaps in motivation and examples from the contents presented in the Chapter III of Neukirch's book?

Comment: Have a look at Cassels's and Fröhlich's Algebraic Number Theory, that you can find here :

http://math.arizona.edu/~cais/scans/Cassels-Frohlich-Algebraic_Number_Theory.pdf

The chapter concerning Tate's thesis covers Riemann-Roch, maybe it could help.

Comment: The chapter *is*, as far as I know, Tate's thesis.

Comment: Also, something else to look at, although I can't remember whether it takes exactly the same approach, is the book _Fourier Analysis on Number Fields_. It is, essentially, a book-length treatment of Tate's thesis.

Comment: That was nice suggestions, I've been reading it without knowing that it was basically Tate's thesis haha. Thanks!